# Subscription website architecture questions + SQL Server & .NET

Tags: sql-server, iis, architecture, subscription

I have a few questions about the architecture of a subscription service I am about to embark on and I am looking for some feedback on how best to set it up.

I won’t have a large amount of customers as Basecamp, maybe a few hundred and was wondering what would be a solid architecture for setting up the customer sites. I’m running SQL Server and .NET on a dedicated machine. Should create a new database for each customer as to have control and isolation of data or keep them all in one database?

I am also thinking of creating a sub-domain for each customer as well so modifications can be made to each site as needed.  The customer URLs would look like this:

https://customer1.foobar.com

https://customer2.foobar.com

I am going to have the ability to ‘plug-in’ reports that will be uploaded to the site so each customer can customize as needed. Off the top of my head this necessitates having each sub domain on its own code-base for the uploading of these reports.

So on the main site the customer would sign up for their new subscription and I would programmatically create a new directory for the customer from the main code base and then create a sub domain pointing to the new directory for the customer and then finally their database.

Does this sound about right? Am I on the right track? How do other such sites accomplish the same thing?

Thanks for letting me bend your ear for a bit on this.

Comment: What direction did you end up going with this, and how did it turn out?

Answer (score 0):

From a maintenance perspective, having a virtual directory for each customer scares me. Having done something similar, I would create separate domain pointers as you are intimating. Then you can check the referral headers to see what should be displayed. I would probably create one main site template and dynamically brand it for each customer. You can still create separate folders for customer specific reports or if you really need custom pages unique to that customer. I just wouldn't make each their own site.

Comment: Scared because if the sites popularity has some decent growth the maintenance would become huge? I would agree. The nature of the site would not have explosive growth though. If by chance it would grow alot..then that would be a good problem.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of separate sites (including databases) is that the fate on one client isn't bound to all others. It'd be easier to upgrade (trial) to a sub-set before deploying to everyone else. The big issue here, as Scot points out, is time. You'd want to have things as automated as possible (and well tested), etc. It's also easy when a client leaves. You can always just back-up their database and send it to them (for example).

Auto-provisioning new sites and databases isn't easy, and the account that does that will need plenty of privileges - so your security testing will need to be better than usual.

A multi-tenancy approach is good for minimizing your time but you do have to be careful, you don't want customers data getting mixed up.

One approach that will work, within the one app (and database), is to make use of HttpHandlers (MVC framework, perhaps) so that some sort of client identifier is in part of the URL - but the folder doesn't have to physically exist (or virtually in the IIS sense). That way you don't have to worry about getting folder permission correct; but you do have to be careful about correctly identifying clients, their ids, and making sure clients can't make calls that use an id that isn't theirs.

https://www.foobar.com/[clientid]/subscriptions

The advantage of this is it's relatively straight forward: everything is in the application, and you don't have to worry about adding new DNS records, setting directory and/or database permissions, etc.